# How to specify fields in MongoDB with multiple condition find query?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is Single document:

```
{
   _id: "...",
   firstName: "john",
   lastName:"Doe",
   cars: [
       {
           "_id": "...",
           "carName": "BMW",
           "carModel": "330",
           "carColor": "silver"
       },
       {
           "_id": "...",
           "carName": "Lexus",
           "carModel": "IS300",
           "carColor": "white"
       },
       {
           "_id": "...",
           "carName": "LADA",
           "carModel": "2106",
           "carColor": "blue"
       }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to select John's BMW's "carColor" only.
Something like this:

```
db.persons.findOne(
        { "firstName": "John", "cars.carName": "BMW" },
        { "_id": 0, "cars.$.carColor": 1 }
      );
```

But this query returns full object like this:

```
{
    cars: [
      {
         "_id": "...",
         "carName": "BMW",
         "carModel": "330",
         "carColor": "silver"
      }
}
```

I tried different query already without .$. symbol:

```
db.persons.findOne(
            { "firstName": "John", "cars.carName": "BMW" },
            { "_id": 0, "cars.carColor": 1 }
          );
```

This version returns only "carColor" properties, but without filtering "carName".
Like this:

```
{
   cars: [
       {
          "carColor": "silver"
       },
       {
          "carColor": "white"
       },
       {
          "carColor": "blue"
       }
   ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Why it's not working?**

> {"firstName": "John", "cars.carName": "BMW"}

means 'where the name is john and where there's AT LEAST one entry in cars array where carName is "BMW"'. But it return complete document, without filtering array.

> { "_id": 0, "cars.carColor": 1 }

don't projects _id, but projects carColor of all entries of cars array.

**SOLUTION**

In fact, you can't achieve exactly what you want with find and projection methods. The better you can do is adding [$ projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) like this :

```
db.collection.find({
  firstName: "john",
  "cars.carName": "BMW"
},
{
  _id: 0,
      "cars.$": 1
    })

**RESULT**

[
  {
    "cars": [
      {
        "_id": "...",
        "carColor": "silver",
        "carModel": "330",
        "carName": "BMW"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But this method have drawbacks :

- you get entire array entry, and not only the color as you want/need
- It return only the first matching entry : if john has 2 BMW, only one will be returned.

**BETTER SOLUTION**

Fortunately, MongoDB provides an other way to achieve this, with aggregation framework, and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      firstName: "john"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      cars: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$cars",
          as: "cars",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$cars.carName",
              "BMW"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      "colors": "$cars.carColor"
    }
  }
])
```

[You can try it here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nbNPcaqjp0E)

**EDIT : Other solution**

you can try this too, with unwind/group stages :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      firstName: "john"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$cars"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "cars.carName": "BMW"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": null,
      colors: {
        $push: "$cars.carColor"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.persons.find({
  firstName: 'john',
  cars: {
    $elemMatch: {
      carName: 'BMW'
    }
  }
},
{
  'cars.$': 1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that you have not more than one "BMW" value in your array then here is a way of getting the result using a single `$project` stage:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "firstName": "john"
        /* for performance reasons, you may want to include the following line which, however, is not required */
        /* this makes sense if you have lots of "john"s with different sets of cars in your database */
        , "cars.carName": "BMW" // this will use an index on "cars.carName" if available
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0, // do not return the _id field
        color: {
            $reduce: { // transform the filtered input array
                "input": {
                    $filter: { // remove all non-"BMW" cars from the "cars" array
                        input: "$cars",
                        as: "car",
                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$car.carName", "BMW" ] }
                    }
                },
                "initialValue": null,
                "in": "$$this.carColor" // just return the color value, nothing else
            }
        }
    }
}])
```