# Retrieve the field from the array

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this

```
[
  {
    "empno": "×325007",
    "vehicle": [
      {
        "valdate": "2020-08-02T13:17z",
        "Inspectvalue": {
          "price": "2000"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want document like this

```
{
"empno":"x325007",
"valdate":"2020-08-02T13:17z",
"price":"2000"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify fields in MongoDB with multiple condition find query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740767/how-to-specify-fields-in-mongodb-with-multiple-condition-find-query)

Answer (score 0):

- keeping them in the array, and including the keys to each element.

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uxtF4w3qBvt)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      newData: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$vehicle",
          "as": "v",
          "in": {
            valdate: "$$v.valdate",
            price: "$$v.Inspectvalue.price",
            empno: "$empno"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "vehicle",
      "empno"
    ],
    
  }
])
```

(you can't have repeated top level fields in JSON).

Or if you want them as top level keys, unwind the elements:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$vehicle"
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      valdate: "vehicle.valdate",
      price: "vehicle.Inspectvalue.price"
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "vehicle"
  }
])
```

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/65l5WkIrpXv)

Comment: I have query like this                 
 db.collection.find({empno:{$in:["x325007","x325008","x325009"]}},{"empno":1,"vehicle.valdate":1,"vehicle.Inspectvalue.price:1})          But I want above  document like this

Comment: add a `$match` and then `$project` stage @Avudainayagam